# IIS7 - asp.net URLs redirect to the root of virtual path error

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, iis, asp-classic

So, all my urls somehow do not work as I want.

```
e.g my website url is http://IPAddress/MyWebsite.
```

'MyWebsite' is my virtual path, and somehow all linkage are messed up since:

```
<a href="~/Default.aspx"> Redirects to http://IPAddress/Default.aspx
or-
Response.Redirect("~/Default.aspx") Redirects to http://IPAddress/Default.aspx
or-
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../static/css/mysupercss.css" /> Links to http://IPAddress/static/css/mysuper.css
```

Instead of redirecting to http://IPAddress/MyWebsite/[THEN THE URL]

anyone knows where my problem is?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You need to change the virtual path into an application. In IIS manager, right-click on the virtual path and select "Convert to application".

Comment: Hi Richard, Thanks for your reply. But I'm afraid I had created my application as an application, with the starting point of '<Default Web Site>\MyWebsite'.

Answer (score 0):

I was having this problem, but I noticed the problem links were only those that were for other pages on the site. Same page anchors with a hash (`<a href=#blah>`) we not causing problems. After some digging around I noticed my affected links to my glossary page were missing the `~/` prefix.

Changing

`<a href="glossary.html#Term_A">Vehicle Configuration</a>`
to

`<a href="~/glossary.html#Term_A">Vehicle Configuration</a>`

got everything working in production again. Without the tilde slash prefix everything worked in development, but once in production with the virtual path in place I was having issues.